# Return time difference in method as JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I return all information in a scream as JSON.

I want to return how long ago it was created.

```
include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper

def as_json(options={})
  super(:only => [:id, :yell_type, :status, :payment_type],
        :include => {
            :trade_offer => {:only => [:id, :title, :description, :price],
                             :include => [:photos => {:only => [:id, :url]}]
            },
            :categories => {:only => [:id, :name]},
            :user => {:only => [:id, :name, :avatar]}
        },
        :methods => [ times_ago(:create_at) ]
  )
end

def times_ago(create_at)
  time_ago_in_words(create_at)
end
```

This returns an error:

```
comparison of Symbol with Time failed
```

How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `methods` on the same level as `include` and `only`. So the return value of the method will be passed in the JSON too. In this case, you should implement a method `times_ago` in the model that returns what you want.

```
def as_json(options={})
  super(
    :only => [:id, :yell_type, :status, :payment_type],
    :include => {
        :trade_offer => {:only => [:id, :title, :description, :price],
                         :include => [:photos => {:only => [:id, :url]}]
        },
        :categories => {:only => [:id, :name]},
        :user => {:only => [:id, :name, :avatar]}
    },
    :methods: [ :times_ago ]
  )
end
```

Comment: guy is possible I pass the parameter date of creação for the method?

Comment: Isn't `created_at` part of the object? If so, you can have `times_ago` method where you can return `self.created_at`. Otherwise, if `created_at` is not part of the object, you can set this value to the object before calling `obj.to_json` and then in `#times_ago` you can use it again this way `self.created_at`